# sql group by not showing all results

Tags: mysql, sql, arrays, join

So i have a query with gets all users, and all user_items. But when i group by user.id it only shows 1 item. When i remove the group it shows all the items but repeats the info.

i want it like this

```
Dan | Laptop
      Car
      Bike
      Shed

Mik | Computer
      House
```

This is the sql

```
SELECT items.name, users.username
FROM users
INNER JOIN items
ON items.userid = users.id
GROUP BY users.id
```

Comment: This is probably something that you should handle in your presentation/report code and not on the server.

Comment: how, just 2 foreach loops or something?

Comment: Yes, maybe something like that; it would depend on what software/code etc you're using to present the data - some reporting systems can do this automatically.

Comment: Yes, that is it. You could also use `group_concat(items.name)`, this will give you all items in one field.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the [GROUP_CONCAT()](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/aggregate-functions-and-grouping/aggregate-functions-and-grouping-group_concat.php) function:

```
SELECT u.username, GROUP_CONCAT(i.name)
FROM users u
JOIN items i ON i.userid = u.id
GROUP BY u.id;
```

It will display a little differently but is very similar to what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

group by both, so you don't collapse all items per user, and don't have dupes in items

```
SELECT items.name, users.username
FROM users
INNER JOIN items
ON items.userid = users.id
GROUP BY users.id, items.name
```

rest has to be handled in your presentation code.